# Display a photo in website (LAMP) from a distant server without HTTP

Tags: php, jquery, html, lamp

I have a website hosted in **LAMP** Server. 
My Lamp server is installed in a Debian **virtual machine**.
My virtual machine is hosted in a distant server.

I face a problem when i try to display an image in my website from the distant server. this is an example of the code i am using :

```
src="\\NameOfDistantServer\Directory\MyImage.jpg"
```

When i try this code, nothing is displyed.

I need your help.

Thank you

Comment: If the code and image is on same server use a local path like `src="images/myimage.jpg"` the src param does not need the `http://servername` just a valid local path. It shoudl also be relative to where the PHP code file is in relation to the image file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found to resolve my problem was to do mount command :

```
mout -t cifs /serverDistant/directoryToshare /directory username pwd
```

After this command i can display all the image like if it was on local directory.
Thank you all for your suggestions, i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be something like:

```
src="http://NameOfDistantServer/Directory/MyImage.jpg"
```

You need to specify the `http`, otherwise the browser thinks the file is on the same server as the html page. You need the `/` slashes because that's what most web servers understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand your question, you have a linux webserver and you want to embed an image from your server inside a HTML file.

When you wrote `src="\NameOfDistantServer\Directory\MyImage.jpg"`, you should add slashes instead of backslashes even if most browsers changes them correctly.

Asyour question is a bit unclear, I will show you most used methods of embedding images on a webpage.

**1. Specify full URL of the image:**

If you want to specify full url, your code should be like this:

```
<img src="http://yourdomainname.something/directory/yourimage.jpg"/>
```

**2. Specify a relative URL of the image:**

If your image is hosted for example, at: `http://example.com/directory/test.png`, and you want to print that image still on the same domain (`example.com`), you can specify the relative path of the image, not the entire path:

```
<img src="/directory/test.png"/>
```

**3. Encode images to base64 to not use files**

If you don't want to host the image inside a file on your server, you can covert it to `base64` and embed it on your webpage as a code, instead of file url. For this, you can use our service which is converting the image you choose to an encoded image: http://netcreator.us/base64-image-encode

Comment: Hi ! first of all i'd like to thank you for your very clear answers, at least now i have an error like : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED , the access to the distant server need a login and a password, i think i should add my virtual machine as a user of the distant server to have an access to the images directory.

Comment: @MehdiSemlali, sorry for the delay. You're welcome! Please tell me more about. If I correctly understand, when you try to open the image directly (eg: http://example.com/directory/image.jpg) in your browser, then it prompts to add username and password?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, actually what i did i've created a new directory in the distant server reachable for all users (it means that no one need to login  to reach the directory) and i put an image in this directory, i double checked that the image is reachable by all users, (right click, property, security)  and when i try to display the image in the website, the console gives an error : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 
I tried all of the solutions you have mentioned in your answer above.

Comment: Can you please provide me the url of the image (eg: `http://example.com/directory/image.jpg`) as to give you the correct code to embed that image? Would be much simple. If the image is reachable on the web (while opening on browser), it should be embeddable.

Comment: Yes of corse, this my code : <img src="//serverintranet1/test/photo.jpg">. 
serverintranet1 is the server where all the data of the compagny is stored...test is the directory i created with all permissions for all users. 
My code + Apache server is in a Virtual machine connected to the intranet. So when i am connected to the intranet of the company i can easly reach the photo by opening a browser and using this url [link](file://serverintranet1/test/photo.jpg ).

Comment: @MehdiSemlali Unfortunately, you can't embed an image using `file://` protocol, on a live website. You can use it only locally. You can read more about, here: http://superuser.com/questions/224500/how-to-display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol. An image can be embedded using `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ftps` or `sftp` protocol. I'd recommend you to create a FTP account on the external server (without username and password, or maybe just username) and then embed the image using: `<img src="ftp://serverintranet1/test/photo.jpg">`

Comment: or `<img src="ftp://username@serverintranet1/test/photo.jpg">` if using an username. IMPORTANT: When creating the FTP account, please don't forget to specify account permissions ONLY TO READ/VIEW files, NOT to write, modify or delete as to avoid getting all your files deleted by a website user.